# How to update orientation when changing from one UITabbar Item to another

Tags: ios, uitabbar

my problem is simple :

- I have a view with a UITabBar and 4 UITabBarItems showing 4 different subviews (4 different UIView classes).
- I want the 3 first views to be Portrait, and the last one to be Landscape or portrait.
- For that, I have setup

  ```
  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
       if (myTabBar.selectedItem.tag==4){
           return YES;
       } else {
           return ((interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)|(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
       }
   }
  ```

...that works fine if I rotate the screen while I am in the fourth view.

BUT...:

-If, when I am in the fourth view landscape, and that I click on any of the three first UITabBarItems, I am moved to the correct view, but the orientation remains landscape, and does not switch to portrait

Note : I have included -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.... in each of the three first views classes, but it did not change a thing.

In other words : my problem is that view orientation is updated after rotating the device, not when the device has rotated and that, I click on another UITabBarItem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this, I think the solution may be to trigger a NSNotification event to the 3 other UITabBar views that were already loaded but that had not received the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" message.

Any other idea ?